# Change color on clicked navigation links CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the color of the **currently active** link on my navigation bar. I have tried using the pseudo-classes active, focus, hover, target, visited but none of them worked.

The visited class doesn't do exactly what I want. The color needs to change depending on which link on the navigation bar I have clicked, not stay forever.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a question which requires code. Please share the relevant code, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: You'll have to add your code here to get help.  The short answer is add an id for each link and assign the color based on `#unique-id:visited, #unique-id:active`, etc

Comment: Updated although I don't think it would be of much help. Just the simplest nav bar in existence.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<style>
a:link {
color: red;
}
a:visited {
color: green;
}
a:hover {
color: purple;
}
a:active {
color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="ping.php" target="#">ping</a>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to [add a class](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) to that item in order to do it. :active, :focus, :visited, etc do not work for the functionality that you need.  You can get the desired functionality by adding an `onclick()` that removes the class from all others and adds it to the last one that was clicked:

```js
var activeId = "";

function addActiveClass(elId) {
  if (activeId !== "") {
    document.getElementById(activeId).className = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(elId).className = "active";
  activeId = elId;
}
```

```css
#home-link.active {
  color: red;
}

#news-link.active {
  color: blue;
}

#contact-link.active {
  color: green;
}

#about-link.active {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" id="home-link" onclick="addActiveClass('home-link');">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news" id="news-link" onclick="addActiveClass('news-link');">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" id="contact-link" onclick="addActiveClass('contact-link');">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" id="about-link" onclick="addActiveClass('about-link');">About</a></li>
</ul>
```